# pywinauto access methods from ListBoxWrapper

Tags: python, pywinauto

I'm using pywinauto do automate some tests on a GUI app. There is a list box that I need to check for some data. The ListBoxWrapper class has these methods:

```
ListBoxWrapper.GetItemFocus
ListBoxWrapper.ItemCount
ListBoxWrapper.ItemData
ListBoxWrapper.ItemTexts
```

https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/pywinauto.controls.win32_controls.html#pywinauto.controls.win32_controls.ListBoxWrapper

How do I access these methods?

Here's what I have till now:
- I created an Application instance and used it to launch the program
- I have a WindowSpecification instance for the listbox

```
listbox = programwindowspec.child_window(title="abcdefg", control_type="ListItem")
```

From here how do I get to the ListBoxWrapper class methods?

PS: I'm not an expert at the OOP side of Python so pls bear with me

EDIT: I used the .children() method to get wrappers for all the controls on the window and then filtered out the list box from the children.

```
window = app.window(handle=w_handle)
for child in window.children():
    if 'List' in child._control_types:
        print(child)
        text = child.texts()
        print(text)
```

And this serves my purpose. But I'm thinking _control_types is a 'private' class attribute. Is it ok to access it directly from outside the class?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you use `backend="uia"` but the docs link you provided is for `backend="win32"`. There are 2 different wrappers for these backends. This is [correct docs for UIA List* related wrappers](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/pywinauto.controls.uia_controls.html#pywinauto.controls.uia_controls.ListItemWrapper).

Using `control_type` in `child_window(...)` search criteria is correct. For the WindowSpecification you can create a **ListItemWrapper** so:

```
list_item = programwindowspec.child_window(title="abcdefg", control_type="ListItem")
item_wrapper = list_item.wrapper_object()

# list all available attributes for a list item wrapper
print(dir(item_wrapper))
```

To create a **ListViewWrapper** (for UIA) you need to use `control_type="List"` or `control_type="DataGrid"` in a WindowSpecification (we use the same wrapper for these 2 control types).